# Can I use a router to share a LAN internet connection that requires an HTTP proxy?

Tags: router, proxy, lan, connection-sharing, http-proxy

At the office I've got one LAN cable, and internet access is through an HTTP proxy listed in the browsers connection settings (automatic proxy configuration URL). Loading the browser triggers a username/password request, and then you're good to go.

What I'd like to do, for my own convenience, is stick my little Linksys Compact WRT54GC router on that LAN cable and broadcast a wireless signal for X devices to use. Having been replaced by beefier hardware at home, the linksys router is otherwise purposeless.

Poking around in the router's web config, I didn't see any option to list an HTTP proxy and U/P set. Is it possible to pass this requirement through to the end-client? Simply plugging it in and setting it to DHCP is not successful. When I connect wirelessly and open a browser with the proxy config URL set properly, I am not prompted for the U/P and cannot browse.

Thank you for any help you might be able to offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

By setting a static IP on the router to match the IP the company's LAN handed me, I can pass the access through to the wireless clients.

Comment: or DHCP, but maybe any IP that is not a duplicate and is on the subnet. and re your question, I guess you've found that you still set the http proxy ip in the browser for each computer.  It could be the company only allow certain IPs within the subnet that might explain if you have to use the IP they want, rather than any unused IP on the subnet.